# Windows .. utility for installing on a number of networked machines?

Tags: windows-10, lan, automation

I'm not a power user of Windows, so wondering about the following:

In the lab we have sets of PCs - generally Windows10 if it matters.  So there are usually 6, 2 or 5 such PCs, sometimes more.

(FTR usually rack-mount format, sometimes Zotak format, sometimes one or more will be a small "kiosk" touch screen.)

All connected via a $10 ethernet router and normal ethernet cables.

So the address of each is something like 192.168.0.100,101,102 etc

FTR they are ***not*** connected to the internet, or any other network.

[image]

Procedure is, someone will build a piece of software, usually about 2GB.

Let's take it as a given that the software has to arrive via an ordinary USB3 stick.

Current situation:

1. someone plugs the USB3 stick in to machine #1 in the diagram, and copies the app folder to the desktop of machine 1
2. .. also indeed tediously deleting the previous build from the desktop
3. unfortunate person then pulls the stick out, and puts it in the next machine, and does the same thing
4. repeat for all 6 machines!
5. and indeed, have to launch it on all the machines and/or quit the old one

What I think would be great:

Again for now let us assume the software build can and must arrive via USB stick.

- There's a magic app on machine 1's desktop.  If you drag a file, file X, to magicApp, that file X then appears on the desktops of the other five machines.  Hooray!

It additionally knows to eliminate the old build folder on all machines; and indeed launch/relaunch on all machines would be a bonus.

It could be this is easy for Windows experts.

Or, maybe we need to build out a small app which wrangles this?  Or indeed, perhaps there exist such products?

Note, one approach I could probably achieve is some sort of fileshare / source control setup - but then you still have to wander around to all 6 machines and click "update", which is almost as bad as wandering around with the USB stick.

How to automate this all "from machine 1" ??  Or at least improve the process?

Comment: thanks for whoever upvoted, power users!  :)   BTW on a set of Macs, I'd do this by just writing a small app.  But then, who needs a set of networked macs?  :O